# MASS equivalent for intel compilers and architectures

Tags: compiler-construction, intel, compiler-optimization

I was looking for if there is an Intel alternative to MASS IBM libraries (Mathematical Acceleration Subsystem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly [Intel Math Kernel Library](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/mklman/index.htm) has such sub-component?

Comment: I know MKL. What is the specific component name?

Comment: I don't know it well, I just had that name in mind. Sorry if it isn't applicable [I'll edit my answer]